# How do I sail rafts in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

There are a bunch of rafts around Zelda: Breath of the Wild, but they don't seem to be interactable and none of the NPCs so far have mentioned them. Have I missed some clue or interaction which makes them usable, or just do I need to use something weird like time freeze to move them around?

Comment: If you want some fun, throw some octorok balloons on the raft. You will fly. This can be helpful in niche situations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out you have to use some [non-Newtonian physics to move rafts](https://www.mic.com/articles/173320/how-to-use-a-raft-in-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-tips-and-tricks-for-sailing-even-faster): *while standing on the raft,* wave a Korok leaf at the sail or push an object held with magnesis against the mast. I could not get the magnesis technique to work with a sword, so either it's been patched out or only certain (heavier?) objects work.

Comment: Funnily enough, you *can’t* use the [Boat Oar](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Boat_Oar) for this purpose

Comment: @Wondercricket Clearly one of the better thought-out features of a game full of physics-based puzzles ;)

Comment: With a properly-shaped sail, it's definitely possible to move forward with a fan mounted on your boat, no Newtonian negation necessary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9cdfUYkrLY

Comment: Note that some rafts are tied to docks, so you may need to cut the rope with a sword.

Answer (score 9):

Get a Korok leaf and stand on the raft.  Use the leaf to blow gusts of wind at the sail.  Doesn't make a whole lot of sense and works a little janky but that's how I got around on them.  I think this is the only way to get to a certain island as well.

Comment: Well, technically, you can also go that certain island by building ice blocks. At least that's how I got there :)

Comment: Or the speed run way by using an explosion from a bomb to launch on object (like a bomb) into you.

Comment: I thought that you can paraglide to a certain island. It has been some time, though, so I may misremember.

Comment: I paraglided but stoked up on stamina boosting food first. I think I had to swim the last bit.

Comment: Are you guys talking about Eventide?